# Correct reading of a txt in arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, filereader

I'm studying JAVA and I have an input txt file that has the following format:

```
Samuel 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
Nicole 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
Josiah 0 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
Mario 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I have a Bet class that says that a bet has a NAME and an ARRAYLIST with its bets, so I need to extract this information from the TXT for the object.

```
public class Bet {

public ArrayList arrayBets = new ArrayList(12);
private String name;
```

I created the following method:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
arrayTotal Bets.add(new Bet());
String[] strings = line.split("\\s+");
arrayTotalBets.get(j).setName(strings[0]);

for(int i = 1; i < arrayTotalBets.get(j).arrayBets.size(); i++) {
int foo = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
arrayTotalBets.get(j).arrayBets.set(i-1, foo);
}
j++;
}
```

I'm managing to split between the name and the integers.

So in this same class I created a for to write what I just read.

```
for(int g = 0; g < arrayTotalBets.size(); g++) {
System.out.println(arrayTotalBets.get(g).getName());
for (int l=0; l<arrayTotalBets.get(g).arrayBets.size();l++) {
System.out.print(arrayTotalBets.get(g).arrayBets.get(l));
}
}
```

This method is just writing:

```
Samuel
Nicole
Josiah
mario
```

Which leads me to believe that I am not being able to correctly insert the integers in the ArrayList.

Where is my split wrong?

Comment: you might wanna print each value before inserting it to make sure you are inserting the correct values, or just debug the function and examine where it's going wrong

Comment: What is this line? `arrayTotal Bets.add(new Bet());` What is `arrayTotal`? A class? This line doesn't make any sense. I doubt this even get compiled. And please: Format and indent your code. It is horrible to read such code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```java
for(int i = 1; i < arrayTotalBets.get(j).arrayBets.size(); i++) {
  int foo = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
  //...
}
```

You should be looping the array you parsed.

```java
for(int i = 1; i < strings.size(); i++) {
  int foo = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
  arrayTotalBets.get(j).arrayBets.set(i-1, foo);
}
```